# Windows 11 doesn't connect automatically to wifi upon wake up from sleep. I have to reboot

Tags: wireless-networking

When I wake up my windows 11 desktop computer from deep sleep, it doesn't connect to wifi automatically. Also, it cannot find any wifi signals. So I have to reboot and everthing is resolved until next deep sleep.

Comment: Did you have this issue with Windows 10? Have you updated your NIC drivers?

Comment: In Device Manager, open Network adapters, right-click your WiFi card and select Properties. If you have a Power Management tab, "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power” should be checked.

Comment: You might also consider updating your power drivers.  Also consider updating BIOS (UEFI).  Make sure your computer manufacturer properly supports this.

Comment: What happens if you deactivate&activate your WLAN device via Device Manager?